# Update HTML Canvas In A Non Blocking Way

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to build a basic renderer that can update the HTML canvas in real time or on a frame by frame basis.

For example, as soon as a pixel is drawn, it'll either update right away to the screen or wait to be collected for a frame, which is then updated (like 25 frames per second)

At the moment this doesn't happen in any way with my code, and I am not sure how to get it to work.

Right now, the canvas only draws to the screen once all operations are complete.

**Canvas.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    main();
});

function main(){
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx  = c.getContext("2d");

    for(var x=0; x<1000000; x++){
        drawPixel(ctx, "200", "200", "200", "255", randomNumber(0, 1000), randomNumber(0, 600));
    }
}

function drawPixel(context, red, green, blue, alpha, x, y){
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ", " + (alpha/255) + ")";
    context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}

function randomNumber(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Canvas Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen"></style>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <canvas height="600" width="1000" id="canvas">

            </canvas>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to know how to make the screen update when I want, instead of it just updating all at once after my code has finished.

EDIT:
Basically, what I want is all the dots to appear gradually so the user can see the dots accumulating. Is there a way I can collect the dots every 25th of a second, render that as a frame and repeat?

Comment: This seems impossible to me given the canvas API.

Comment: Well you can setup a timer every 40 ms and update your canvas from there. Or is there a catch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to break the "synchronousness" of your `for` loop as the browser is completing all `drawPixel` calls in the same repaint.

Instead, use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to call a function once at the browser's natural repaint interval (this, instead of `setTimeout` or similar). something similar to:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var counter = 0;

function run() {
  drawPixel(0, 0, 0, 255, randomNumber(0, canvas.width), randomNumber(0, canvas.height));
  counter++;
  // If our counter is less than 10000, run again at the next repaint
  if (counter < 10000) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
  }
}

function drawPixel(red, green, blue, alpha, x, y){
  context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ", " + (alpha/255) + ")";
  context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}

function randomNumber(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

run();
```

```html
<canvas height="100" width="100" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `requestAnimationFrame` API can be used to allow the browser to decide when it's time to redraw. The problem you have to solve is that your JavaScript likely takes much longer than the 16 milliseconds or so between frames.

There are a variety of ways to handle this, but most of them are going to involve executing the draw commands in batches. Here is one possible solution:

```
// These variables would need to be outside the main function scope
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx  = c.getContext("2d");
var batchSize = 1000;
var currentItem = 0;
var lastItem = 1000000;

// Execute a batch of draw commands
function main() {
  // Queue the next frame
  window.requestAnimatoinFrame(main);

  // Draw the pixels
  for(var batchEnd = currentItem + batchSize; currentItem < batchEnd; currentItem++) {
    drawPixel(ctx, ...);
  }
}

// Queue the first frame
window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an interval timer with a limited number updates in each iteration, as in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    main();
});

function main(){
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx  = c.getContext("2d");

    var pixelsPerTick = 1000;
    // one thousand iterations each tick
    window.setInterval(function(){
      for(var x=0; x<pixelsPerTick; x++){
        drawPixel(ctx, "200", "200", "200", "255", randomNumber(0, 1000), randomNumber(0, 600));
      }
    }, 1000 / 25); // 25 times per second


}

function drawPixel(context, red, green, blue, alpha, x, y){
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ", " + (alpha/255) + ")";
    context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}

function randomNumber(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```